# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'. flutter Error

Tags: flutter

[image: This is the flutter doctor]

Everything is correctly installed

**I already added the JAVA_HOME**

[image]

**Also I added the system variable path**

[image]

but showing me the error

[image]

Comment: Your JAVA_PATH is pointing to a JRE.

Answer (score 0):

I was pointing to the JRE file instead of JDK.